# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_CFRelease"

Tags: undefined-symbol

I am quite new to the Unix world and I am trying to install a software called Meep for physics simulations. To get this I need to install a lot of libraries on my Mac OS X 10.10.5; I succeeded in many of them but I had the following error while commanding 'configure' for the script called *pkg-config* which works over glib.

```
CCLD     pkg-config
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFStringGetCString", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFStringGetCStringPtr", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFURLCopyFileSystemPath", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_CFURLCreateFromFSRef", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_FSFindFolder", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
  "_kCFAllocatorSystemDefault", referenced from:
  _find_folder in libglib-2.0.a(libglib_2_0_la-gutils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Looking around I have understood that could be a linker problem to those symbols, but essentially I have no idea to solve the problem. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What's the complete compiler/linker command? I had the same problem and I recently solved it.

Answer (score 13):

You need to add:

```
-framework CoreFoundation
```

to the link command line of your project.

Comment: I randomly ran into this with a `cmake` project on macOS 10.13.2 and a project that uses `CoreMIDI` and this fixed the problem.

Comment: I found I also had to add `-framework Carbon`, otherwise `_FSFindFolder` would not be found.